# How to force npm install from registry instead of creating symlink?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo with the structure in the diagram below. `my-app` is dependent on `my-lib` . `my-lib` is published to the registry. When I run `npm install` , a symlink to the `my-lib` directory is created in `node_modules` instead of downloading `my-lib` from the registry as shown in the diagram below:

```
root
|--package.json
|
|--node_modules
|  |--symlink to my-lib directory
|
|--my-app
|  |--package.json
|  |  |--"dependencies":{"my-lib": "1.0.0"}
|  |
|  |--node_modules
|     |--nothing here
|
|--my-lib
   |--package.json
   |  |--"version": "1.0.0"
   |
   |--node_modules
      |--nothing here
```

How do I force npm to install `my-lib` 1.0.0 from registry?

The reason why I want this behaviour is because sometimes `my-lib` is still in the middle of development and I don't want my apps to use the dev code in `my-lib`. I want my apps to use the published version of `my-lib`.

If npm can't achieve this behaviour, I'm happy to use yarn as well.

Comment: If you are using [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) then this is by design, so you're getting what you asked for. Remove the lib from the workspaces config if you want to download from registry, but then local dev becomes more cumbersome. Figure out what you want because you're asking for mutually exclusive outcomes. Maybe set up a separate repo for testing the published version of the lib.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with Yarn 2+ by setting the `enableTransparentWorkspaces` to `false` in your `.yarnrc.yml` configuration file:

```
enableTransparentWorkspaces: false
```

Disabling this option means that instead of the default behavior which would always resolve to local workspace (if version matched), it will instead always resolve to registry. It also means that if you want to resolve a package to a local workspace, you will have to use the `workspace:` protocol.

More information can be found in [Yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#enableTransparentWorkspaces).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get success with running:

```
yarn cache clean
```

It is the default behaviour of yarn to cache the packages and use these cached version of the packages instead of fetching it from the registry if the required package with the same version already exists in its cache.

You can try clearing the package cache before building the consumer application.